# Postgres: How to join table with values from jsonb[] column

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, jsonb

I have two tables as follows

```
accounts
 ------------------------------------------
|  ID  |           LOCATIONS               |
|------------------------------------------|
|  1   |  [{ "id" : 1}, { "id" : 3 }]      |
|------------------------------------------|
|  2   |             []                    |
 ------------------------------------------

regions
 ----------------------------
|  ID  | DATA               |
|---------------------------|
|  1   | {"name": "South"}  |
|---------------------------|
|  2   | {"name": "West"}   |
|---------------------------|
|  3   | {"name": "North"}  |
|---------------------------|
|  4   | {"name": "East"}   |
---------------------------
```

`locations` is of type `jsonb[]`

Now I wanted to get result as follows

```
 ------
| NAME |
|------|
| South|
|------|
| North|
 ------
```

Please help with the postgresql query to get this.

Comment: Side note: The schema of the JSON looks pretty static to me. You should consider not to abuse JSON but use relational means like (lookup and/or linking) tables and columns instead.

Comment: There are more column, keys and values, i just reduced them for better understanding. @stickybit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited for `jsonb[]` type:**

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f6272e58589246129671fbf2a4d0d393)

```sql
select
  r.data ->> 'name' as name
from
  accounts a
  cross join unnest(a.locations) al
  inner join regions r on r.id = (al ->> 'id')::int
```

---

**P.S: for `jsonb` type:**

You can use `jsonb_to_recordset` function and `CROSS JOIN` to join JSON array record with table.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c484989468953b7331cf9c0875a66106)

```sql
select
  r.data ->> 'name' as name
from
  accounts a
  cross join jsonb_to_recordset(a.locations) as al(id int)
  inner join regions r on r.id = al.id
```

Comment: function jsonb_array_elements(json[]) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: I edited my answer for `jsonb[]` column. You should tell your data type structure clearly to get better answer

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS()` along with cross joins such as

```sql
SELECT r.data->>'name' AS "Name"
  FROM accounts AS a,
       regions AS r,
       JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(a.locations) AS l
 WHERE (value->>'id')::INT = r.id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dd21d5a340d70938545c64c0a1c0be59)</kbd>
PS. if the data type of `locations` is `JSON` rather than `JSONB`, then just replace the current function with `JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS()`

Comment: what is value in the where condition?

Comment: function jsonb_array_elements(json[]) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: then your column is of `json` type instead of `jsonb`. So, just replace `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS` with `JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS` @CrazyCat

Comment: Can you explain this more?

Comment: Hi @TeachMe , I don't know what kind of an explanation you need, but presumingly [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a5600cfa7e6a455a4d1e88bedd034728) would help to explain. Best wishes.

Comment: Is this the syntax for a cross join?
`FROM accounts AS a,
       regions AS r,
       JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(a.locations) AS l`

Comment: yes, exactly the same, just notation differs... @TeachMe It's just a shorthand, while comma-seperated joins are not recomended to use for the other type of joins (INNER, OUTER), or for the cases the join types should be mixed up. eg. such as using a `CROSS JOIN` along with a `LEFT JOIN`